# Python HTMLParser Not Reading Whole File

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, html-parsing

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class HTMLParserDos(HTMLParser):

    full_text = ""

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.full_text += data
        return self.full_text

h = HTMLParserDos()

file = open('emails.txt', 'r')

h.feed(file.read())
file.close()

print h.container
```

This code is getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/laurenstrom/Google
>   Drive/PYTHON/RANDO_CALRISSIAN/html_parse", line 15, in 
>       h.feed(file.read())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py",
>   line 108, in feed
>       self.goahead(0)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py",
>   line 148, in goahead
>       k = self.parse_starttag(i)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py",
>   line 229, in parse_starttag
>       endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py",
>   line 304, in check_for_whole_start_tag
>       self.error("malformed start tag")   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py",
>   line 115, in error
>       raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos()) HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 7, column 18

I'm not sure what I'm missing about .feed() but I can't seem to find anything about why it won't just read the whole file.

Comment: What is inside emails.txt?

Comment: http://textuploader.com/t6so

Answer (score 0):

Your are asking the HTML parser to parse a file most of which isn't HTML.  It is tripping over line 7 of your file. Which is :

> ```
> Return-Path: <Tom@sjnetworkconsulting.com>
> ```

I would imagine it is seeing the < and assuming that is HTML which of course it is not.